# how to set font to grid in extjs

Tags: fonts, extjs, grid, set

i want to set a DVB-TTYogesh Normal (true type) font to grid.
for that i added the following to grid,
 style:'font-family:DVB-TTYogesh'.

but the data in the grid still show "pcmcÁÖß´Ö.³ÖÖêÃÖ»Öê" like this and i want it
in actualform

Answer (score 0):

I assume that font is actually installed on your system (and it must be installed on all users' systems to display for them).  Also, check that your page is using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: yes that font is installed and my js file has UTF-8 encoding
style:'font-family:DVB-TTYogesh'
when i just am tring to do the following for checking is it apply the font or not ,
style:'font-family:Arial Black'
it does not show any effect on my grid
what is the problem here???

Comment: In that case your CSS is probably wrong.  Make sure you are specifying your rule like this: .x-grid3-row td { font-family: ... }