# how to set style to grid in extjs

Tags: coding-style, extjs, grid

how to set style to grid so that it display font-family
i am tring like this
   style: {'font-family': 'Brush Script MT',
           'font-weight': 'bold'
           }
but result does not show according to it.

and i m also trying

style:'font-family:Brush Script MT;
      font-size:300px', 
but it also not show the result according to it..
can u pls tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in ExtJs but one way to do this is to use getRowClass in the GridPanel to define a function that returns a css class.

Something like

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store:my_store,
    view: new Ext.grid.GridView({
        //forceFit:false,
        enableRowBody:true,
        ignoreAdd: true,
        deferEmptyText: false,
        emptyText: 'No Record found.',
          getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){ // rp = rowParams
                if(record.get('f_severity') == 'Critical')
                {
                    return 'x-grid3-row red-class';
                }
                  }
        }),
        bbar:pagingBar,
        plugins: filters,
....
```

In this example, 'red-class' is a custom CSS class.

Comment: its not working doesnot give any error but also not give result

Comment: This is for overriding default styles at the row level based on business logic.  This has nothing to do with setting the default grid style.

Answer (score 2):

Font styles are set at the table cell (td) level, so you also have to override them there.  Add this to your stylesheet (after the Ext JS stylesheet):

```
.x-grid3-row td {
    font-family: 'Brush Script MT';
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

BTW, this is basically a duplicate of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406905/how-to-set-font-to-grid-in-extjs).  No need to ask multiple times.